# Catch X-Frame-Options Error in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling, dom-events

Is there any way to catch an error when loading an iframe from another domain. Here is an example in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/2Udzu/ . I need to show a message if I receive an error.

Here is what I would like to do, but it doesn't work:

```
$('iframe')[0].onerror = function(e) {
   alert('There was an error loading the iFrame');
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `onerror` is applicable only for script errors. Frame content error checking must be done using any other method. Here's one example.

```
<script>
  function chkFrame(fr) {
    if (!fr.contentDocument.location) alert('Cross domain');
  }
</script>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/" onload="chkFrame(this)"></iframe>
```

Due to cross domain restriction, there's no way to detect whether a page is successfully loaded or if the page can't be loaded due to client errors (HTTP 4xx errors) and server errors (HTTP 5xx errors).

Comment: That is what I thought. Just wanted to see if anyone found a way around it. I will accept your answer by the end of today.

Comment: The onload event handler won't work in Safari, see http://www.jeffdoubleyou.com/bin/view/Blog/JQueryDetectWhenIFrameLoaded for a workaround.

Comment: I'm getting `fr.contentDocument` equal to null even if the site is **not** cross domain

Answer (score 0):

If both the parent site and the iframe-url is accessible by you, a way to know that the page is fully loaded (without "sameorigin" issues) is sending a message *([postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage))* from the child to the parent like this;

**Parent site (containing the iframe)**

```
//Listen for message
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    if (event.data === "loading_success") {
        //Yay
    }
});


//Check whether message has come through or not
iframe_element.onload = function () {
    //iframe loaded...
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!iframeLoaded) {
            //iframe loaded but no message from the site - URL not allowed
            alert("Failure!");
        }
    }, 500);
};
```

**Child site (URL from the iframe)**

```
parent.postMessage("loading_success", "https://the_origin_site.url/");
```

You could get `the_origin_site.url` by using a server-side language like PHP if you want the possibility for multiple origins

---

The accepted answer only works if the domain you're trying to put in an iframe is the same as the one you're requesting from - this solution works for cross-domain where you have access to the scripts on both domains.

Comment: If you control both domains, most people would just allow iframes on the other site, so this doesn't help most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code to detect whether a x-frame-option error occured or another with jquery

```
$(iframe).load(function (e) {
  try
    {
    // try access to check
    console.log(this.contentWindow.document);
    // Access possible ...
    }
  catch (e)
    {
    // Could not access. Read out error type 
    console.log(e);
    var messageLC = e.message.toLowerCase();
    if (messageLC.indexOf("x-frame-options") > -1 || messageLC.indexOf('blocked a frame with origin') > -1 || messageLC.indexOf('accessing a cross-origin') > -1)
      {
      // show Error Msg with cause of cross-origin access denied
      }
    else
      {
      // Shoe Error Msg with other cause
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work in cross-domain scenarios, at least not in Chrome 94.