# Check if a website can be embedded in IFRAME via Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, angular

I have an `iframe`:

```
<iframe id='url-iframe' src='example.com' width="600px" height="400px"></iframe>
```

I want to check if this `example.com` can be embedded in `iframe` so that I could open it in a new tab if it's not.
I'm using Angular 2 with Typescript. So a solution written in vanillajs or typescript would be nice.

Comment: There is a duplicate [Catch X-Frame-Options Error in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062081/catch-x-frame-options-error-in-javascript), but it won't work in current browsers anymore. At least in Chrome this test fails.

Comment: Yep, I cannot use that solution for now. This is so frustrating.

Comment: Whenever you ask questions you should mentions other questions and answers targeting your topic. On the one hand this will show that you did some research and on the other hand other people trying to find a solution will know which approach do not work.

Comment: @t.niese I will notice, thanks.

Comment: Is it an option to detect that server side?

Comment: I'm using angular2 with typescript. Server side detection is not an option, I think...