# Catch set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin error in js

Tags: javascript, iframe

I load some page in iframe.
I get the error

```
Refused to display 'url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

How can I handle this type of error in javascript, and show my message for this case?
`window.onerror` doesn't catch this error.
Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062081/catch-x-frame-options-error-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

DOMException comes to help here.

I got a trick working as follows: [have not tested cross-browser!]

Define iframe's onload event handler defined as

```js
$('#myIframe').on('load', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        try {
            console.log($('#myIframe')[0].contentWindow.document);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            if (e.message.indexOf('Blocked a frame with origin') > -1 || e.message.indexOf('from accessing a cross-origin frame.') > -1) {
                alert('Same origin Iframe error found!!!');
                //Do fallback handling if you want here
            }
        }
    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: frame.contentWindow is null even if the frame isn't cross domain