# Is there a DOM Event that will be sent when iFrame refusing to display content?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is anyone aware of a DOM event that I can use in a Vue component that will call a function when the content in an iFrame window refuses to display because of cross-domain issues? The `load` event is always activated, and retrieving results from the url doesn't send any errors that can be picked up by the `error` event. I've looked through the Event reference documentation on MDN, but nothing strikes me as suiting my needs.

Comment: No event that I know... and if MDN doesn't reference it then the answer is most probably "no". Cfr [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062081/catch-x-frame-options-error-in-javascript) for an idea how to detect such an issue, but it's not perfect, and doesn't imply an event.

Comment: I'll give your reference a shot. I just wanted to check that I wasn't missing something, or misunderstanding one of MDN's listings. Thank you.